# Implement routeboxer into code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm new to google map and JS. For learning I trying to create some service for car trip with google map, google places, and rote boxer.

Now I create all what I need, so working google map,places but now I really don't know how I can implement routeboxer into this to make it search be only into boxes.

I try here: http://jsbin.com/inicah/23 but map won't to show.

Does somebody tell me how I can do that?

Here is my code without routeboxer and all works fine: http://jsbin.com/inicah/22

also I was try to implement routeboxer from @geozipcode example: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_RouteBoxerPlaces.html

*Sorry for my english, its really bad, but i'm learning hard*

Comment: You have 3 errors in code  `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = 23:34
Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined 23:1212
Uncaught ReferenceError: remoteWindow is not defined spike.js:88`

Comment: yes but how I can solve that?

Comment: Look at the lines indicated in the error message.  Learn what they mean and fix them. There are lots of [tutorials on debugging javascript](https://www.google.com/?q=tutorial+debug+javascript)

Comment: ok, but just tell me , Do I go on a right way to do this with routeboxer?

Comment: I have error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = ? so what this really means

Comment: @geocodezip please help me to do this, its really important to me. If need I want to pay you for implement routeboxer into my code.

Comment: I am not available for hire, sorry.

Comment: ok, then help me for free to implement this code into mine :) ;)

Comment: I ;m your fan boss ;)

Comment: `Line 34 Unexpected token = `  you have not closed `google.maps.Map object` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#google.maps.Map **ie** `);` 
`Line 1212 route is not defined` **CLUE** Where have you defined it?? In `spike.js:88 remoteWindow is not defined` find out **WHY**

Comment: please edit my jsbin code

Comment: If I edit it you will not learn anything.If you don't learn from this(**HOW TO DEBUG**) you will keep coming back with silly errors you want answered.

Comment: no, just edit please I will learn from example ...